# How to resolve urls for static assets with apache configuration?

Tags: apache, webpack, webserver

Front end developer here - I just inherited a server (Mac Pro) to host my prototypes within our network.  There's already an apache server set up on it, but I don't know much about it's config.  This is a shared server, so while the server root is set up at `/Users/Shared`, I only have permissions to place my prototypes at

`/Shared/mydiv/mydept/prototypes`

I build my site with webpack and it places static assets in a `dist` directory.  The server configuration is working; users can browse to `sharedserver.url.com/mydiv/mydept/prototypes` and the index.html is served correctly.

The problem is that index.html references `scripts.js`, also located within the `dist` directory, but the web server is looking for them in the server root at sharedserver.url.com, which obviously returns a 404.
Likewise, I need to reference some fonts located in `dist/fonts`.

```
sharedserver.url.com/   <-- APACHE TRYING TO ACCESS STATIC ASSETS HERE
|_mydiv/
   |_ mydept/
      |_ prototypes/
         |_ _ dist/
                |_ index.html
                |_ scripts.js  <-- REALLY WISH APACHE LOOK FOR STATIC ASSETS HERE 
                | _ _fonts/
                       |_.eof,.ttf,etc.
```

I've read a little about using vhosts but the module is not already loaded in httpd.conf (commented out) and I don't want to cause a conflict with existing configuration, which I don't yet fully have my head around.  I've also read about .htaccess files but AllowOverride is set to None in httpd.conf

Are there any other (easyish) ways to get apache to look for my static assets in my directory?

edit: referencing scripts in index.html like this:

```
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you just tell how are you including 'How are you including JS file in your HTML'?

Probably you are using an Absolute Path '/dist/scripts.js'.
Rather, you can try with './scripts.js' in the index.html

Comment: I am referencing it like so:
     <script src="scripts.js"></script> - no absolute path.

Comment: Just try with ./script.js instead of directly giving script.js